# Any portable tricks to obtain namespace name in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have some well-formed code looks like this:

```
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(Foo)
inline void test() {
    string s = xxx;
}
NAMESPACE_END(Foo)
```

So, is there any portable tricks by using the `NAMESPACE_BEGIN()` macro to obtain namespace name "Foo" in `test()`?

I'm thinking of something like this, but it would surely cause symbol redefinition:

```
#define NAMESPACE_BEGIN(x) \
    namespace x { \
        inline const char *_curNamespace() { \
            return #x; \
        }
#define NAMESPACE_END(x) \
    }
```

There's also a workaround looks like this, but that's not very convenient

```
#define NAMESPACE_NAME Foo
// using a header file so that we can use #ifdef guard
#include "MyNamespaceBegin.h"
...
#include "MyNamespaceEnd.h"
```

**EDIT**:

- Why I need this:

  I'm using much of macro to generate codes to achieve some
  dynamic reflection logic (yes, not static template reflection),
  it's all right within class scope by using static member function,
  but does not work for namespaces
- Why not to manually declare the name getter once:

  What I want is something like this:

  ```
  // the global default version
  const char *_curNamespace() {return "";}

  namespace X {
      // the local namespace version
      const char *_curNamespace() {return "X";}

      // some verbose reflection register code
      ...
      registerSomething(_curNamespace());
      ...
  }
  ```

  Of course, all of the verbose register code should be generated by macro

  And, app level user should not care about the `_curNamespace()`,
  so, I want to **simplify the user's usage**,
  by using a custom `NAMESPACE_BEGIN(xxx)` macro **at any case**
- If you are still curious about what I'm doing,
  check this: https://github.com/ZFFramework/ZFFramework

  I'm using lots of tricks to achieve fully dynamic reflection in pure C++,
  to achieve some of my fancy thoughts,
  for now, this project is just for fun,
  I have no idea whether it has practicability

**EDIT2**:

For now, I think the best workaround should be like this:

```
#define NAMESPACE_BEGIN(ns) \
    namespace ns { \
        extern const char *__curNS();
#define NAMESPACE_END(ns) \
    }
#define NAMESPACE_REG(ns) \
        const char *__curNS() {return #ns;}
```

- app level users still only need to care about `NAMESPACE_BEGIN`
- `NAMESPACE_REG` must be declared exactly once, in source file

  - if not, undefined symbol would happen
  - if more than once, duplicated symbol would happen
  - although it's annoying and sometimes you need additional source file
    to hold the `NAMESPACE_REG`,
    the strict rule should prevent user from forgetting the ugly workaround

Comment: "*I'm thinking of something like this, but it would surely cause symbol redefinition:*" Why? You have marked it as `inline`.

Comment: It's actually a neat idea. In C++17 you can even dispense with the function. Just make it `inline constexpr const char *_namespace_ = #x;` - something like the standard  `__func__` identifier.

Comment: @Acorn multiple definitions of an `inline` function can exist, but must be in separate TUs; and it's possible to reopen a namespace, causing a clash.

Comment: @Quentin: Of course, I am assuming this was to be put in a header file with guards. Anyway, by itself, it would not introduce odr violations, even in a cpp file, unless, as you say, it is repeated.

Comment: @Acorn - Even with include guards there can be a clash. Separate files in the same library will need to open the namespace, presumably with these macros. Think if the standard library did this. You'd include `<vector>` and `<string>` and get a duplicate definition error.

Comment: Maybe you could define a class with a randomized name, using a mix of source file name / line number to have a unique name in that namespace, then get the name of the type, which will include the namespace in it, then drop the last part

Comment: @OlivierSohn that requires RTTI, and, if I'm not wrong, the format of `typeid`'s name is not ensured

Comment: @ZSaberLv0 right, and it's not at compile time... if you don't need portability, with gcc you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` : I tried it it will return something like that :  `void Foo::test()` (or `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION` may be usefull on more platforms, but not everywhere) Also related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325960/is-it-possible-to-get-a-string-that-would-containing-namespace-and-class-name-at

Comment: @OlivierSohn I think the hard part is crafting a macro that will define the probe function but not cause multiple definitions errors :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: OP can simply guard the macro locally if it is expected to be used in several headers for the same namespace, the same way full headers are typically guarded.

Comment: @Acorn - That is likely to cause issues when two different libraries use this macro. The OP is writing a framework. So I imagine their end goal is reusability.

Comment: Do you ultimately need *just* the namespace name, or you are combining it with other scope names (like class or function name)?

Comment: @n.m.just the namespace name, I want to do some custom registration

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hmm... The framework part was not there before. Still, I don't see the problem. I mean, the name `_curNamespace` is not meant to be part of the public interface of each library (and given the last edits of OP, it would seem it is indeed an implementation detail, with the actual value in a single source file of the library).

Comment: @Acorn - The problem... is that the macro can't be "guarded" on a per namespace basis. Only globally. The first use in a TU will be the only use. So only *one* namespace from included headers can benefit. All others will see a missing identifier.

Comment: @StoryTeller: So you mean two different libraries, exposing each a header that is using this framework, and then a client including both of the headers. OK, that would be an issue indeed, assuming those libraries want to use the framework in their public headers. I am adding an answer with some preprocessor magic which supports that.

Comment: Don't use identifiers that start with an underscore for any purpose at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are making much fuss over something that is trivial to implement.

First of all, use of `NAMESPACE_BEGIN` and `NAMESPACE_END` seems unnecessary to me. I don't see how that is more readable or useful than

```
namespace Foo
{
}
```

If getting the name of the `namespace` is important/useful, add a trivial function.

```
namespace Foo
{
   inline std::string get_name() { return "Foo"; }
}
```

Small sized real world applications need thousands of lines of code. Large sized real world applications need millions of lines of code. From that perspective, implementing a one line `inline` function is a very minor task.

Comment: @PaulSanders "don't clog your program up with 50 lines of arcane TMP to achieve what can be done in 1 line" is a competing principle

Comment: I downvote because duplication of information is a source of future bugs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sort of.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Very loosely :)

Comment: _implementing a one line inline function is a very minor task._ Until you have a bad day and mess it up.

Comment: @PaulSanders, I don't know about what everybody else does but from my experience, the string representation of a class name is an additional piece of information that needs be encoded for most persistent object types. Extending that to a `namespace` seems natural to me. If mistyping the string representation of a `namespace` or forgetting to correct it after the name of a `namespace` has been changed can mess things up in an application, the application has bigger problems.

Comment: I think you just made my point for me.  If the string representation is (subtly) wrong then, sure, something somewhere will probably break.  Eventually.

Comment: @MM With reference to the OP's original suggestion (the first one), just what 50 lines are these, pray? Sure, some of these proposed template solutions are a mess, but that doesn't mean there might not be a nice, neat solution to this problem.  Telling the OP to hard-code his namespace name twice doesn't cut it here for me

Comment: @PaulSanders, it seems like we, meaning SO users, are divided on the topic. Many of us don't mind typing the name twice while many of us do.

Comment: Agree.  But please see my answer (I just posted it, and I think I might have cracked it). I don't mind typing the name twice either (I do it when declaring and then subsequently referencing a variable all the time), I just want the compiler to tell me when I get it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I downvoted you - I very rarely do that - but I thought long and hard about it and finally decided that I should, for reasons I have already given in the comments.

Comment: @PaulSanders, not a problem. If we didn't downvote when we think it is needed, SO will lose a lot of its value.

Comment: You're right.  That comment, all by itself, is an education.  Thank you sir, you are a gentleman.

Comment: @PaulSanders, you are kind. I welcome kind people in every sphere of life :)

Comment: Thank you, I have my moments :)  Still finding my way here at SO.

Answer (score 1):

This solution employs a bit of preprocessor magic and has these features:

- Namespace is mentioned only once
- Access to a macro containing the unquoted name
- Access to a macro containing the quoted name
- Support for repeating the same namespace
- Support for different namespaces
- Misuse of the BEGIN/END macros is detected
- Cleanup, i.e. no extra macros defined outside the BEGIN/END block

It does not support nested namespaces.

Example of usage:

```
#include "framework.hpp"

#define NAMESPACE_NAME Foo
#include NAMESPACE_BEGIN
    // Here you have access to NAMESPACE_NAME (unquoted, i.e. Foo)
    // and also to NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING (quoted, i.e. "Foo")
#include NAMESPACE_END


// NAMESPACE_NAME and NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING do not exist
// outside the block, so they cannot be misused


// Different namespaces in the same TU are supported
#define NAMESPACE_NAME Bar
#include NAMESPACE_BEGIN
    inline std::string f()
    {
        return NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING;
    }
#include NAMESPACE_END


// Repeating the same namespace is also supported
#define NAMESPACE_NAME Foo
#include NAMESPACE_BEGIN
    inline std::string f()
    {
        return NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING;
    }
#include NAMESPACE_END
```

---

The implementation follows:

**`framework.hpp`**

```
#pragma once

#define NAMESPACE_BEGIN "framework_namespace_begin.hpp"
#define NAMESPACE_END "framework_namespace_end.hpp"
```

**`framework_namespace_begin.hpp`**

```
#ifndef NAMESPACE_NAME
#error "NAMESPACE_NAME not defined"
#endif

#define NAMESPACE_IN_NAMESPACE 1

#define NAMESPACE_NAME_DO_STR(X) #X
#define NAMESPACE_NAME_STR(X) NAMESPACE_NAME_DO_STR(X)
#define NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING NAMESPACE_NAME_STR(NAMESPACE_NAME)

namespace NAMESPACE_NAME {
```

**`framework_namespace_end.hpp`**

```
#ifndef NAMESPACE_IN_NAMESPACE
#error "NAMESPACE_IN_NAMESPACE not defined"
#endif

}

#undef NAMESPACE_NAME
#undef NAMESPACE_NAME_STRING
#undef NAMESPACE_IN_NAMESPACE
```

Answer (score 1):

You know what?  I think I might just have a viable solution for this.  It's actually very simple, and it's very close to the OP's original suggestion (which really only had the problem of a potential duplicate definition if you wanted to open the namespace twice in the same translation unit).  You just have to think a bit laterally and not be too precious about seeing your namespaces being bracketed by macros instead of curly braces.

So let me just lay it out here, because there's really nothing to it, and then I'll explain why I personally happen to like it.

Code:

Macros:

```
#define DECLARE_NAMESPACE(ns) \
namespace ns {\
    static constexpr const char *_curNamespace = #ns; \
}

#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE(ns) \
namespace ns { \
    static_assert (ns::_curNamespace, "BEGIN_NAMESPACE: namespace has not been declared");

#define END_NAMESPACE }
```

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

DECLARE_NAMESPACE (Foo)
BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Foo)
    void print_namespace_name () { std::cout << _curNamespace << "\n"; }
END_NAMESPACE

BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Foo)
    void another_print_namespace_name () { std::cout << _curNamespace << "\n"; }
END_NAMESPACE

DECLARE_NAMESPACE (Bar)
BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Bar)
    void print_namespace_name () { std::cout << _curNamespace << "\n"; }

    DECLARE_NAMESPACE (BarBar)
    BEGIN_NAMESPACE (BarBar)
        void print_namespace_name () { std::cout << _curNamespace << "\n"; }
    END_NAMESPACE
END_NAMESPACE

int main ()
{
    Foo::print_namespace_name ();
    Foo::another_print_namespace_name ();
    Bar::print_namespace_name ();
    Bar::BarBar::print_namespace_name ();
}
```

Output:

```
Foo
Foo
Bar
BarBar
```

Now this is obviously very straightforward to implement and also easy to use and has no obvious limitations.  In particular, it can handle nested namespaces (as shown in the code above) and opening a namespace twice in the same compilation unit also works (again, this is shown in the code snippet).

But, but, but, don't we still have to type in the name of the namespace twice, and wasn't that the very thing we were trying to avoid to eliminate typos?

Well, sure, we have to type the name in twice, but so what, live with it.  Point is, with this particular set of macros, the compiler will now catch any typos for us.  Let's prove that by deliberately putting one in.  So this:

```
DECLARE_NAMESPACE Whoops
BEGIN_NAMESPACE whoops
END_NAMESPACE
```

Generates this (I couldn't find a better way of formulating the `static_assert`, sorry):

```
prog.cc:12:24: error: '_curNamespace' is not a member of 'whoops'
     static_assert (ns::_curNamespace, "BEGIN_NAMESPACE: namespace has not been declared");
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:27:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BEGIN_NAMESPACE'
     BEGIN_NAMESPACE (whoops)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And more importantly this (and this is why we need the `BEGIN_NAMESPACE` macro):

```
DECLARE_NAMESPACE (Bar)
BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Bar)
    DECLARE_NAMESPACE (BarWhoops)
    BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Barwhoops)
    END_NAMESPACE
END_NAMESPACE
```

Generates this:

```
prog.cc:12:24: error: '_curNamespace' is not a member of 'Bar::Barwhoops'
     static_assert (ns::_curNamespace, "BEGIN_NAMESPACE: namespace has not been declared");
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:42:5: note: in expansion of macro 'BEGIN_NAMESPACE'
     BEGIN_NAMESPACE (Barwhoops)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which is just dandy.

So, you know, what's not to like?

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J9JlOLVtL10O7EpA) - uncomment line 3 to see those compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable and change its value with 'NAMESPACE_BEGIN' and 'NAMESPACE_END'

the variable __name represent the current full namespace position

like "abc::def::detail"

```
std::string __name = "";

std::string & __append(std::string & str, const char * ptr) {
    if (!str.empty()) {
        str.append("::");
    }
    str.append(ptr);
    return str;
}

std::string & __substr(std::string & str, const char * ptr) {
    if (str.length() == strlen(ptr)) {
        str.clear();
    } else {
        str = str.substr(0, str.length() - strlen(ptr) - 2);
    }
    return str;
}

#define NAMESPACE_NAME __name

#define CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2)
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __COUNTER__)
#else
# define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __LINE__)
#endif 

#define APPEND_NAME(x) std::string ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(__start_name) = __append(__name, #x)
#define SUBSTR_NAME(x) std::string ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(__end_name) = __substr(__name, #x)

#define NAMESPACE_BEGIN(x) \
    namespace x { \
        APPEND_NAME(x); 

#define NAMESPACE_END(x) \
        SUBSTR_NAME(x); \
    }
```

then you can use the NAMESPACE_NAME macro for the full name or you can extract the last name from it

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but I think it's still not work because: using `__LINE__` would cause redefinition if same in two file, static variable would initialized at entry thus `__name` would not change any more

Comment: although my solution somewhat works it's mostly a concept how it could be implemented, I only tested it in one file in which case it works although it creates a lot of pollution maybe you can use a macro for __name,  __start_name and __end_name and just define it differently in every source file before the includes and only use this in a source file, not the header file, still I don't think it is a viable solution because you can easily misuse it and create errors

Comment: there was a type error in the last define (NAMESPACE_END): SUBSRACT_NAME instead of the SUBSTR_NAME now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way.  The core idea came from the line of thought:

> Q: How can I define multiple things with the same name accessible from the same scope?
>
> A: Make them all functions with different parameter types. And if all of them have identical bodies, it doesn't matter which one gets called.
>
> Q: How can I generate an unlimited set of different parameter types?
>
> A: A class template.
>
> Q: How can I make sure a call to that set of overloaded functions will never be ambiguous?
>
> A: Make sure the binary relation "is implicitly convertible from" is a complete ordering on the parameter types, and use a unique minimal element for the argument type.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct NamespaceHandleObj {
    template <const NamespaceHandleObj* Handle1, const NamespaceHandleObj* Handle2>
    struct less : public std::bool_constant<std::less<>{}(Handle1, Handle2)> {};
};
template <>
struct NamespaceHandleObj::less<nullptr, nullptr> : public std::false_type {};
template <const NamespaceHandleObj* Handle1>
struct NamespaceHandleObj::less<Handle1, nullptr> : public std::false_type {};
template <const NamespaceHandleObj* Handle2>
struct NamespaceHandleObj::less<nullptr, Handle2> : public std::true_type {};

template <const NamespaceHandleObj* Handle>
struct NamespaceParamType
{
    constexpr NamespaceParamType() noexcept = default;
    template <const NamespaceHandleObj* Other,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<NamespaceHandleObj::less<Other, Handle>::value>>
    constexpr NamespaceParamType(NamespaceParamType<Other>) noexcept {}
};

#define NAMESPACE_UTILS_TOSTR1(x) #x
#define NAMESPACE_UTILS_TOSTR(x) NAMESPACE_UTILS_TOSTR1(x)

#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE(ns) \
    namespace ns { \
        namespace { \
            constexpr NamespaceHandleObj namespace_handle_{}; \
            constexpr const char* current_ns_(
                NamespaceParamType<&namespace_handle_>) noexcept \
            { return NAMESPACE_UTILS_TOSTR(ns); } \
        }

#define END_NAMESPACE }

#define CURRENT_NAMESPACE (current_ns_(NamespaceParamType<nullptr>{}))
```

The code above is C++17, but it wouldn't be hard to port it to previous versions, even all the way to C++03.

Comment: unable to port to VS2008 (a bit old version but perfect to test portability), since only class can have default template param, and I'v no idea how to modify your solution to bypass that :(